# Why some polygons with values are not shown on a choropleth map plot

Tags: python, plot, geopandas, choropleth

I'm new to geopandas & visualization in maps.

I want to plot a choropleth map with the values of a certain column ("EINWOHNERZ") in a geopandas dataframe, I noticed there are some n.a values, so I drop them before plotting. I made sure that the type of values I'm trying to plot are float. But for some reason, not all the values are displayed on my map.

The geojson file I used is at:[here](https://github.com/xiaoshir/gis_example/tree/master/fixed_boundaries.geojson)

Here is the unexpected result map with a lot of white space, although they do have values.

[image]

Below are my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df=gpd.read_file("fixed_boundaries.geojson")
df.dropna().plot(column="EINWOHNERZ",figsize=[20,10], legend=True)
```

I know not all of them are being plotted based on the length of the two series below.

```
print(len(df["EINWOHNERZ"]),
     len(df["EINWOHNERZ"].dropna()))
```

Where I did wrong?

Comment: Data on the link are incomplete (and it is not geojson, but incomplete shapefile). I assume that your geodataframe has NaNs in other columns as well, so these rows are dropped as well. Not just those where NaNs are in "EINWOHNERZ". But I am unable to check this assumption.

Comment: Hi you are absolutely right! I added the anwser to my question:)

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
swiss_gemeinde[["EINWOHNERZ","geometry"]].dropna().plot(column="EINWOHNERZ", figsize=[20,10], legend=True)
```